# Any way to enable user interaction while viewing fullscreen video in iOS browsers?

Tags: ios, iphone, video

My research tells me that there is now way to escape fullscreen video viewing in iOS browsers on iPhone or iTouch. It also seems there there is no way to modify the native controls that are displayed along with the video. Is the user in a total blackbox while viewing video in this case?

I'm trying to find someway for a user to indicate that they like a video as it is playing. Is there anything I can do that isn't a hack? If not is there any indication from Apple that they will ever be willing to change this? I'd rather not make an app out of this project.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can play a video in line on an iOS browser, if this is what you are aiming for although there are restrictions - updated answer:

**Play video inline in a browser on iOS**

Safari on large screen iOS (iPad) *should* support inline video (I don't have iPAD hand to verify this still works...).

Safari on 'small screen' iOS (i.e. iPhone) will not support inline video as standard. There is at least one workaround which will allow it but this does bypass much of the native video playback performance gains so it may not meet your needs. It is a work in progress still as you will see from the link, but try the demo on an iPhone browser - you need to hit the small play button beside the video, rather than the one on top of the video at the time of writing:

- https://github.com/newshorts/InlineVideo

**Playing inline in a UIWebView on iOS**

Take a look at this Apple Developer page:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW31

In particular:

> allowsInlineMediaPlayback
>
> > A Boolean value that determines whether HTML5 videos play inline or use the native full-screen controller.

and:

> Discussion
>   The default value on iPhone is NO.
>
> In order for video to play inline, not only does this property need to be set on the view, but the video element in the HTML document must also include the webkit-playsinline attribute.

Comment: You can't change allowsInlineMediaPlayback in a webpage. Your UIWebView has to be in an app to do that.

Comment: Misread your question - updated answer with more info. Interestingly I'm not sure why Chrome won't allow inline as it is an app that uses a web view as far as I am aware so they should be able to include this. I thought in the past it did but I just tested on iOS9 and it goes full screen.